# Ctrl + backspace not working in JetBrains Rider

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, rider

I want to use `Ctrl+Backspace` to delete a word in `Jetbrains Rider`, my keymap setting is `visual studio keymap`.
But It works well in `Visual Studio 2019`.
It has been bothering me for a long time.

[image: Ctrl+Backspace not working when the code tip window showing,]

[image: But It works well in visual studio]

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings->Keymap` and check if `Delete to Word Start` option is set to `Ctrl+Backspace`

[image]

Comment: It 's not work when the code tips windows displaying, but the strange thing is I can use it on my home's pc, not work on my office 's pc.